How to parse accented file names in a batch file to open a file in a relative position?
I got a lot of use out of this answer, thank you so much. It works just fine, but what if I have accented characters in the target file name?
This works fine:

Target E:\GD\A\'Modernist Villa' (Malaga)
Batch file location E:\GD\R\11

start "loadPDF" "file:///%~d0/GD/A/'Modernist Villa' (Malaga).mkv"

But if the target directory has a ꞈ character, (which I use for sorting), or the target file name has an accented character (e.g. á), the batch file is not happy.
i.e.

Target E:\GD\ꞈA\'Modernist Villa' (Málaga)
*Batch file location E:\GD\R\11

start "loadPDF" "file:///%~d0/GD/ꞈA/'Modernist Villa' (Málaga).mkv"

It's not that critical a thing, but it would be nice to respect the origin language in naming files.
PS
I know that start "loadPDF"  is incorrect usage, but I am using a modified file from code to open a PDF. Is there a start "loadvideo", or just not neccessary?
It would also be nice to have a main video open in one video player, and supplementary files open in another video player, to avoid one file opening to close a previous. (Although I've just started using AnyDVD which opens multiple instances, so it's fine, but would be nice to know).
i.e. open a video file, another video file, and a PDF file
Renamed path and file name to exclude unsupported characters

Please read first: Why are Danish characters not displayed as in text editor on executing batch file?
There are several methods how to encode the character á.
There can be used a single byte with decimal value 225 (hexadecimal 0xE1) on using the Windows-1252 encoding as used by Windows GUI text editors in Western European countries like Windows Notepad and saving the file as ANSI encoded file. ANSI means here single byte per character encoding using a code page.
But the execution of chcp (fully qualified file name: %SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com) in a command prompt window tells a user which character encoding is used by the Windows Command Processor cmd.exe by default on interpreting the bytes of a batch file as characters according to the country/region configured for the user account. That is code page 850 for Western European countries which encodes the character á with a single byte with decimal value 160 (hex. 0xA0). That is the non-breaking space character in Windows-1252 encoding.
There are other character encodings like the Unicode encoding UTF-8 which encodes the character á with two bytes with the decimal values 195 and 161 (hex. 0xC3 0xA1). In UTF-16 little endian are used two bytes with the decimal values 225 and 0 (hex. 0xE1 0x00) for encoding the character á.
However, there is used the file URI scheme which has its own rules for encoding characters described by the URL specification. The characters in a file:// URI (or URL) must be encoded first in UTF-8 and the bytes (not characters) of the UTF-8 byte stream must be next percent-encoded.
The character % must be escaped in a batch file with one more % for being interpreted as literal character and not as the beginning of a batch file argument reference like %~d0, beginning/end of an environment variable reference like %CD% , or beginning of a loop variable reference like %I inside a FOR loop.
If the batch file is stored in the directory E:\GD\R\11 and the video file is with fully qualified file name E:\GD\ꞈA\'Modernist Villa' (Málaga).mkv, the required line in the batch file for playing this video by the Windows GUI application associated by the user with the file protocol is:
start "" "file:///%~d0/GD/%%EA%%9E%%88A/%%27Modernist%%20Villa%%27%%20(M%%C3%%A1laga).mkv"

The modifier letter low circumflex accent character ꞈ is in UTF-8 encoded with three bytes with the decimal values 234, 158 and 136 (hex. 0xEA 0x9E 0x88) and therefore percent-encoded with %EA%9E%88 with one more % left to each % for being interpreted as literal percent sign by cmd.
The character ' is also percent-encoded with %27 although it works in most cases also using just the character ' as the web browsers usually associated with files opened with using a file URI scheme are fault-tolerant against encoding syntax mistakes in URLs.
A normal space character must be encoded in a URI/URL with %20.
The character á is percent-encoded with %C3%A1 in the URL.
Renaming the directory ꞈA to just A and the video file to Modernist_Villa_Malaga.mkv for a fully qualified file name E:\GD\A\Modernist_Villa_Malaga.mkv consisting only of ASCII letters and underscores would make it possible using in the batch file either
start "" "file:///%~d0/GD/A/Modernist_Villa_Malaga.mkv"

or even just
start %~d0\GD\A\Modernist_Villa_Malaga.mkv

The second line starts the application associated with the file extension .mkv which is usually a video playing application.
Batch file coding can be simple on using simple directory/file names.
How the application associated with the file protocol or the file extension .mkv handles the passed URL/file name cannot be controlled from within a batch file. The cmd internal command start results in calling usually the Windows kernel library function CreateProcess for running the executable as separate, detached and parallel executed process, but in this case in calling the ShellExecuteEx function for finding first out which application is associated with file respectively .mkv before CreateProcess is called for running this application with the command line as stored in Windows registry.
It would be necessary using start with the executable file name and with perhaps offered options of this application to control the video playing behavior.
Run in a command prompt window start /? and read the output usage help. If an argument string must be enclosed in ", it is required to specify a console window title as first argument for the command start even if the started application is a Windows GUI application for which no console window is opened at all. "" as first start argument specifies an empty console window title which is best on started application is a Windows GUI application.
There can be executed in a command prompt window assoc .mkv for getting output the .mkv file extension association like:
.mkv=WMP11.AssocFile.MKV

There can be executed next ftype WMP11.AssocFile.MKV to get output the file type registration with the command line used by ShellExecuteEx called also by Windows File Explorer on double clicking on a file with file extension .mkv.
WMP11.AssocFile.MKV="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" /prefetch:6 /Open "%L"

%L is replaced by the passed long file name. This command line is used next for calling CreateProcess for running the application which opens the file which means for a video file in playing the video.
The execution of assoc file shows the file protocol association:
file=URL:File Protocol

The execution of ftype "URL:File Protocol" results just in the output of an error message because of the file protocol is not a file type. There is evaluated also the file extension .mkv to find out which application to start for opening the file specified with the file URI scheme.
The usage of directory/file names with non-ASCII characters could be further problematic if the application for opening such a directory or file is not full Unicode aware and does not support passing command line parameters in Unicode to the executable. In such cases the short 8.3 file name must be used if the file system is configured for creation of short 8.3 file names as it is usually the case on home computers.
for /R "%~d0\GD" %I in ("'Modernist Villa' (M?laga).mkv") do start %%~sI

This command line should result in the execution of:
start E:\GD\AD249~1\'MODER~1.MKV

There are hopefully not multiple video files found recursive in directory E:\GD and its subdirectories matching the file name wildcard pattern 'Modernist Villa' (M?laga).mkv with wildcard character ? (zero or one character) for the non-ASCII character.
This solution does not work if the file system has not created short 8.3 names for the directory ꞈA and the file 'Modernist Villa' (Málaga).mkv.
There could be used the following command line in the batch file if the video playing application supports passing file names in Unicode as command line parameter to the executable.
for /R "%~d0\GD" %%I in ("'Modernist Villa' (M?laga).mkv") do start "" "%%I"

